# Using menuSubItem to organize inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to use the `menuSubItem` functions to organize my inputs since I'll have a lot. What I'm finding though is that the conditional Panel is minimizing the whole menuItem and not expanding them. And what I'm also seeing is that the body doesn't change when I click on different tabs. Am I using conditionalPanels right?

```
    library(needs)
needs(
    shiny,
    ggplot2,
    tidyverse,
    shinydashboard,
    DT,
    shinycssloaders,
    plotly
)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
header = dashboardHeader(
    # tags$li(class = "dropdown",
    #         tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 80px}"),
    #         tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 80px}")),
    #title = tags$img(src='logo.png',height='100',width='200')
    
)


sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
        id = 'panelsbar',
        style = '"overflow-y:auto; max-height: 600px; position:relative;"',
        
        menuItem('Data Input', tabName = 'data'),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.panelsbar== 'data'",
            fileInput(
                "file",
                "Upload CSV files",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = ("text/comma")
            )
        ),
        menuItem('Simulate',tabName = 'sim_tab',
                 helpText('Adjust Simulation Parameters'),
                 
                 menuSubItem('Promotion Parameters', tabName = 'promo'),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 div(id = 'sidebar_promo',
                     conditionalPanel("input.panelsbar==='promo'",
                                      radioButtons('promoType',label = 'Promotion Definitions:',
                                                   choices =c('Aggregated','Role Defined'),
                                                   selected = 'Aggregated',inline=F,width='200px'),
                                      conditionalPanel('input.promoType==="Aggregated"',
                                                       sliderInput('promoAll','Set promotion rate:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),           
                                      ),
                                      conditionalPanel('input.promoType==="Role Defined"',
                                                       
                                                       
                                                       helpText('Set Promotion Rates for each role'),
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'promoRole1','Role 1:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'promoRole2','Role 2:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'promoRole3','Role 3:', value = 25,min = 0, max = 100, step = 5), 
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'promoRole4', 'Role 4:', value = 25, min = 0, max = 100,step = 5)
                                      )
                     )),
                 menuSubItem('Candidate Slates', tabName = 'hire'),
                 div(id='sidebar_hire',
                     conditionalPanel("input.panelsbar==='hire'",
                                      radioButtons('hireType',label = 'Candidate Slate Definitions:',
                                                   choices =c('Aggregated','Role Defined'),
                                                   selected = 'Aggregated',inline=F,width='200px'),
                                      conditionalPanel('input.hireType==="Aggregated"',
                                                       sliderInput('hireAll','Set candidate slate rates:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),           
                                      ),
                                      conditionalPanel('input.promoType==="Role Defined"',
                                                       helpText('Set the Candidate Slate Diversity'),
                                                       h5('0 = Females, 100 = Males'),
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'hireRole1',
                                                           'Role 1:',
                                                           value = 25,
                                                           min = 0,
                                                           max = 100,
                                                           step = 5
                                                       ),
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'hireRole2',
                                                           'Role 2:',
                                                           value = 25,
                                                           min = 0,
                                                           max = 100,
                                                           step = 5
                                                       ),
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'hireRole3',
                                                           'Role 3:',
                                                           value = 25,
                                                           min = 0,
                                                           max = 100,
                                                           step = 5
                                                       ),
                                                       
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'hireRole4',
                                                           'Role 4:',
                                                           value = 25,
                                                           min = 0,
                                                           max = 100,
                                                           step = 5
                                                       ),
                                                       
                                                       sliderInput(
                                                           'hireRole5',
                                                           'Role 5:',
                                                           value = 25,
                                                           min = 0,
                                                           max = 100,
                                                           step = 5
                                                       )
                                      ))),
                 menuSubItem('Turnover Rates', tabName = 'turnover'),
                 div(id='sidebar_turnover',
                     conditionalPanel("input.panelsbar==='turnover'",
                                      radioButtons('turnoverType',label = 'Turnover Definitions:',
                                                   choices =c('Aggregated','Role Defined'),
                                                   selected = 'Aggregated',inline=F,width='200px'),
                                      conditionalPanel('input.turnoverType==="Aggregated"',
                                                       sliderInput('turnoverAll','Set turnover rate:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),           
                                      ),
                                      conditionalPanel(
                                          "input.turnoverType==='Role Defined'",
                                          helpText('Set the turnover rate for each role'),
                                          sliderInput(
                                              'turnoverRole1',
                                              'Role 1:',
                                              value = 25,
                                              min = 0,
                                              max = 100,
                                              step = 5
                                          ),
                                          sliderInput(
                                              'turnoverRole2',
                                              'Role 2:',
                                              value = 25,
                                              min = 0,
                                              max = 100,
                                              step = 5
                                          ),
                                          sliderInput(
                                              'turnoverRole3',
                                              'Role 3:',
                                              value = 25,
                                              min = 0,
                                              max = 100,
                                              step = 5
                                          ),
                                          
                                          sliderInput(
                                              'turnoverRole4',
                                              'Role 4:',
                                              value = 25,
                                              min = 0,
                                              max = 100,
                                              step = 5
                                          ),
                                          
                                          sliderInput(
                                              'turnoverRole5',
                                              'Role 5:',
                                              value = 25,
                                              min = 0,
                                              max = 100,
                                              step = 5
                                          )
                                      ))
                     
                 )),
                 actionButton('go','Run')
        ))
        
       
       
        
    



body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(
            tabName = 'data',
            wellPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('table'))),
        tabItem(
            tabName = 'sim_tab',
            fluidRow(h2('Average of Distribution',align = 'center')),
            fluidRow(h5('Below is a table of the average distribution from the simulation',align='center')),
            fluidRow(
                wellPanel(
                    DT:::dataTableOutput('simDataTable') %>%
                        withSpinner(color="#ee1100")
                ),
                fluidRow(h2('Average of Distribution',align = 'center')),
                
                fluidRow(
                    wellPanel(
                        plotlyOutput('simPlot')
                    )
                ))
        )
        
    ))





ui = shinydashboard::dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = 'red',
                                   tags$head(tags$style(
                                       HTML(".sidebar {
                      height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;
                    }")
                                   )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use conditionalPanel for the initial menuItem.  You can try this...

```
shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(width=300,
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarMenu(id = "panelsbar",
    #style = '"overflow-y:auto; max-height: 600px; position:relative;"',
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
    menuItem('Data Input', # tabName = 'data1' ,
    #conditionalPanel( condition = "input.panelsbar== 'data'",
      menuSubItem(
        fileInput(
          "file",
          "Upload CSV files",
          multiple = TRUE,
          accept = ("text/comma")
        ),tabName = 'data' )
    ),
    menuItem("Simulate",  tabName = 'sim_tab',
             helpText('Adjust Simulation Parameters'),
             menuItem("Promotion Parameters",   tabName = 'promo' ,
             #  div(id = 'sidebar_promo',
             #     conditionalPanel("input.panelsbar==='promo'",
                                  
                                  radioButtons('promoType', label = 'Promotion Definitions:',
                                               choices =c('Aggregated','Role Defined'),
                                               selected = 'Aggregated',inline=F,width='200px'),
                                  conditionalPanel('input.promoType==="Aggregated"',
                                                   sliderInput('promoAll','Set promotion rate:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),
                                  ),
                                  conditionalPanel('input.promoType==="Role Defined"',
                                                   helpText('Set Promotion Rates for each role'),
                                                   sliderInput(
                                                     'promoRole1','Role 1:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),
                                                   sliderInput(
                                                     'promoRole2','Role 2:',value = 25,min = 0,max = 100,step = 5),
                                                   sliderInput(
                                                     'promoRole3','Role 3:', value = 25,min = 0, max = 100, step = 5),
                                                   sliderInput(
                                                     'promoRole4', 'Role 4:', value = 25, min = 0, max = 100,step = 5)
                                  )
                 #)
             #),
             ),  ## new line
             menuItem('Candidate Slates', tabName = 'hire'),
...
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ahhh! didn't know you could nest menuItems. thank you very much